# SAS column input

Tags: input, sas

I found a weird output when implementing the following codes.

```
data ex;
    input a $ 1-80 b $;
    datalines;
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

The data set ex is:

```
a       b
1 2     3
```

Then

```
data ex2;
    input a $ 1-81 b $;
    datalines;
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

The data set ex2 is:

```
a        b
3 4      5
```

Finally, I create a txt file which contains:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

and run

```
data ex3;
    infile '/.../test.txt';
    input a $ 1-10 b $ ;
```

The data set ex3 is:

```
a        b
3 4      5
```

Can anyone explain how buffer and PDV work to get the weird results? Thanks a lot.

All results are based on SAS Studio (university edition).

Answer (score 0):

I get this

```
 Obs     a     b

  1     1 2    3
```

with this log

```
27         data ex;
28             input a $ 1-10 b $;
29             datalines;

NOTE: LOST CARD.
RULE:      ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9----+----0                     
33         ;;;;
a=5 6 b=  _ERROR_=1 _N_=2
NOTE: SAS went to a new line when INPUT statement reached past the end of a line.
NOTE: The data set WORK.EX has 1 observations and 2 variables.
```

Are you telling the whole story?

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. I correct the question now. Next time, I'll double check before posting it.

Answer (score 0):

When you read from datalines (cards) SAS will round the linesize up to a multiple of 80. It does not do this when reading from an separate file.

So in this example:

```
data ex;
  input a $ 1-80 b $;
cards;
1 2
3 4
5 6
;
```

You read the full 80 column card image into A and then when you try to read B it needs to go the next line and so it reads until the first space from line 2. Hence `a='1 2'` and `b='3'`.  Then when it tries to read the next observation it reads the line into A and runs out of information to read into B so it stops when it reads past the end of the input and no second observation is written.

In the second example you tried to read MORE than a full line into A, so SAS went to a new line and read `'3 4'`. Not sure why it didn't also try to read more than 80 from that line, but looks like it didn't. So then when it wants to read B it gets the `5` from the last line.

Your last example is just like the second one. Your external file probably only had 5 characters on the first line. So when you tried to read 10 characters it jumped to the next line to read A and then had to go to the last line to find something to read for B.

If you want it to only read data from one line instead of "flowing" to the next line in search of data then add the `TRUNCOVER` option to your INFILE statement.  When reading from card images you can use INFILE CARDS or INFILE DATALINES.